# Is it possible to make chat application like Whatsapp with react-native, firestore and socket.io?

Tags: firebase, react-native, socket.io, google-cloud-firestore

I am going to make a chat application as like as whatsapp with following technologies:

1. react-native           ---> front-end language
2. cloud firestore        ---> for database
3. socket.io              ---> for being realtime

Just for 100000 users.

I am worry about `react-native peformance, at least 10000 same time connection and database read, write and delete per day.`

Comment: Answering your question, yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but unless you have some special reason to use `socket.io`, updates made to `firebase` are propagated pretty dang quick to devices listening for updates.

I'm using `react native` and `firebase` in one of the apps I'm developing, and an update made on one device, shows up on the other device almost as fast as I can change my eyes from the first device to the second - that is of course assuming you have decent internet, but if you don't I imagine `socket.io` will have similar latency issues.

The speed issues you are going to run into when using `React Native` usually deal more with processing power - something like 3d graphics or needing to render significant changes at game like speeds. So doing a chat app should be just fine with react native.

Comment: Thank you,
but someting in react-native works slow, like flatlist scrolling fast shows blank area.
and also while react-native does not compile the code I am worry about security,
and about firestore there is some problem with multi users Update.
for example 5 users message to me at the same time, here I dont know how to listen to all messages from different collections in different list of users

Comment: @Muhammad, that’s true, but there are performance enhancements you can do to flatlists to avoid some of that, and to get that to happen you have to be scrolling pretty fast. As for fire base, that’s a whole other question, but if you really think you are going to have that much traffic that fire base will have a hard time keeping up you will need a different solution. If your question is more of a logistical one, “how do I listen for many collections on fire base” it should also really be its own question. You asked here if it was possible to do what you asked, not for anything else.